How do you write "Seeking the House Builder" in Pali script?
I'm looking to get a tattoo and have these word written in Pali. Can you help me with how to write this in Pali script?

There is no Pali script

There's no Pali script but you can get it written in Devanagari (script used by Sanskrit and Hindi), Thai, Sinhalese or Burmese.

Gaha karaka........
Gaha = house.
Karaka = builder.

In Hindi Devanagari  it is     गहकारं गवेसन्तो

Pāli does not have its own unique script. Historically, it has been written using various other scripts including Roman.
The Tipitaka, was first written down in the Sinhala script in Sri Lanka, around the 1st century BCE.
Sinhala has been used in Sri Lanka since about the 6th century BCE.
In Sinhala script Seeking the House Builder in Pali language is සෙඑකින්ග් ථෙ හොඋසෙ බුඉල්දෙර්

There is no Pali script. In Hindi Devanagari it is गहकारं गवेसन्तो
Gahakaram gavesanto: lit: "I who have tried to find the builder of the house"

